# Nullreference exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, nullreferenceexception

I am creating a microsoft WPF project and ran into the following hindrance:

> Null reference was unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My VS 2010 points to the following line of code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab06Wpf.Properties.Settings.AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Not sure why this is happening, I have a similar project where I have a similar connection string and it runs itself just fine.

The ConnectionStrings argument `Lab06Wpf.Properties.Settings.AppConnectionString` is valid and the connection has been tested.

Any leads anyone?

Comment: you should test everything against null maybe?

Comment: Use the debugger, break on the exception, and inspect *the assumption* at the current point in code. Something is `null`. Playing guessing games on SO is only so much fun.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab06Wpf.Properties.Settings.AppConnectionString"]
```

That is returning null and your are calling `ConnectionString` on it.  You need to find out why it is returning null.  Use your debugger to see what `ConnectionStrings` contains and why your call is failing.